# css breaks in production of Gatsby, MaterialUI

Tags: css, material-ui, gatsby

I have a gatsby website that uses MaterialUI Components.

Somehow the css styles get applied to the wrong components of my website. I got the following code that is related to the problem.

Layout.js

```js
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline/>
      <Header onMenu={() => setMenuOpen(true)}/>
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider
```

Header.js

```
const NavigationBar = ({onMenu}) => {
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({target: (typeof window !== `undefined` ? window : undefined)})
  const data = useStaticQuery(query)
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Slide appear={false} direction="down" in={!trigger}>
        <AppBar color={"primary"}>
          <Toolbar disableGutters={true}>
           ...
            <LaptopAndWider>
              {data.dataJson.navigationPrimary.map(x =>
                <Button key={x.title} component={Link} to={x.path} color="inherit" underline={"none"}>
                  <Box height="70" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" display="flex"> // This styles (height, flexBox) gets applied to the wrong item
                    <Typography variant={"h6"}>
                      {x.title}
                    </Typography>
                  </Box>
                </Button>
              )}
              {data.dataJson.navigationSecondary.map(x =>
                <Button key={x.title} component={Link} to={x.path} color="inherit" underline={"none"}>
                  <Box height="70px" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" display="flex">
                    <Typography variant={"body1"}>
                      {x.title}
                    </Typography>
                  </Box>
                </Button>
              )}
            </LaptopAndWider>
           ...
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </Slide>
      <Box height={82}/>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

And the following index.js

```
const IndexPage = ({data}) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Box> // Gets applied to this Box
      <GatsbyImage fluid={data.file.childImageSharp.fluid}
                   />
    </Box>
    ...
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

I use the following plugins in gatsby which could be related:

```
  plugins: [
    ...
    `gatsby-theme-material-ui`,
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-layout`,
      options: {
        component: require.resolve(`./src/components/Layout`),
      },
    }
  ],
```

When I use gatsby develop, the jss/css is working as expected. But in Production (gatsby build && gatsby serve) the css which is applied to the navigation bar items (`<Box height="70" alignItems="center" justifyContent="ce....`) is applied to the Box which surrounds my Image. This is just one of the Problems that happen in production, just to show the Problem. All styles are odd and broken in prod.

CSS on the NavigationBar Item
[image]

CSS on the Div around the gatsby-image (which should have no styles)
[image]

What I have tried:

- Removed `gatsby-plugin-offline` (That seems to cause Problems, dont need it atm anyway)
- Reordered components on all kinds of pages
- Removed `gatsby-plugin-emotion` (no changes)
- Removed `.cache` `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and reinstalled packages
- Updated all packages
- Replace the rehydrate function with render (which did break even more things)
- Read to a bunch of related gitlab issues, which mostly suggest removing the `gatsby-offline-plugin`, clearing caches and updating packages.

A sample that shows the problem is available here: https://github.com/Console32/BrokenCss

Comment: I saw your current [cloundfront site](https://d1xkmzkrm4co56.cloudfront.net/) working correct right?

Comment: @ShinaBR2 no it is not, it breaks on the 2nd render, If you navigate to any other site and back to home, you see how it should look

Comment: Are u using the gatsby styled component plugin?

Comment: @claudios no, you can view the conifg here https://github.com/Console32/BrokenCss/blob/master/gatsby-config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem originates from the `LaptopAndWider` component. This component uses `MediaQuery` from `react-responsive` to implement hiding things on different screen sizes. The SSR did therefore never render the Material UI Components below LaptopAndWider, which resulted in missing styles. CSR did work, which is why after navigating back and forth the correct styles where applied.

Replacing `MediaQuery` from `react-responsive` with `Hidden` from `@material-ui/core` solves the problem.

```
            <Hidden mdDown>
              {data.dataJson.navigationPrimary.map(x =>
                <Button key={x.title} component={Link} to={x.path} color="inherit" underline={"none"}>
                  <Box height="70" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" display="flex"> // This styles (height, flexBox) gets applied to the wrong item
                    <Typography variant={"h6"}>
                      {x.title}
                    </Typography>
                  </Box>
                </Button>
              )}
              {data.dataJson.navigationSecondary.map(x =>
                <Button key={x.title} component={Link} to={x.path} color="inherit" underline={"none"}>
                  <Box height="70px" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" display="flex">
                    <Typography variant={"body1"}>
                      {x.title}
                    </Typography>
                  </Box>
                </Button>
              )}
            </Hidden>
```

Answer (score 0):

This conflict with the CSS classnames results from having a [multitree setup in your application](https://cssinjs.org/react-jss/?v=v10.4.0#multi-tree-setup).

You can resolve this conflict by providing a classname generator for generating the classes. This way Gatsby and MDX will use the same classname generator to generate classnames.

Install `react-jss`

```sh
yarn add react-jss
```

In `src/components/Layout.js`, provide the same classname generator,

```
import React from 'react';
//...
import {createGenerateId, JssProvider} from 'react-jss';

const generateId = createGenerateId();

const Layout = ({children}) => {  
  //...
  return ( 
    <JssProvider generateId={generateId}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {/* ... */}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </JssProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sadly the issue persists even when i specify the Id (I have added a branch to the demo repository that contains your suggestion [here](https://github.com/Console32/BrokenCss/tree/jssProviderTest)

Comment: And removing mdx entirely from the demo project did not change anything as well.